# How to get the availability zone details for a running instance

Tags: java, amazon-ec2

I am iterating through the running instance list returned by DescribeInstances API. I would like to know how can I retrieve the availability zone for each of these instances.

Answer (score 12):

The availability zone can be accessed with:

```
instance.getPlacement().getAvailabilityZone();
```

Comment: Is this API available in .NET SDK? i could not locate it.

Comment: which programming language did you use? In the python boto API it is `instance.placement == "us-west-2a"`

Answer (score 12):

Surprised no one has posted this yet, which is the best, fastest, and easiest way to do this AFAIK.

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone
```

Comment: This is a good thing to know about, but doesn't actually answer the question asked. It's something you could do from within an instance, not when iterating through instances using the API.

Comment: Good point, @Steve. I suppose if you had the ssh keys you could send this command to each instance in a loop, but it's true I misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the availability zone details for a running instance until those instances have connected with ELASTIC LOAD BALANCER (target groups).

Answer (score -2):

There is no API for this:

I did it as follows:
1. Use API to get the current available zones.
2. Loop through the returned zones, set filter on DescribeInstances foreach of these and get the instance details.